# How to remove a settings section from the Theme Customization API preview pane?

Tags: customization, settings-api, core

I am currently working on a theme that uses the Wordpress Customization API and I need to remove some pre-existing sections from the customization preview pane. Is there somewhere like a global variable holding an array of the sections perhaps (in true Wordpress style) I can unset the navigation section in particular?

Please see attached image for what I am talking about. I've circled it in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`remove_section`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L590) method of the `$wp_customize` object:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse8170_customize_register' );
function wpse8170_customize_register( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'section-id-to-remove' );
}
```

Comment: Wow. I did not realise there was a remove_section method. I did some searching, but should have looked in the codebase.